# How is matching done in LLVM tablegen?

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to learn `tablgen`. However I'm having difficulties with it. I'm using [this](http://jonathan2251.github.io/lbd/index.html) tutorial to do it. I'm stuck on [this](http://jonathan2251.github.io/lbd/llvmstructure.html#llvmstructure-f13). From this image I can't figure out how `tablegen` is doing the matching, i.e. converting from one type of dag to another. Would anybody be able to explain it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what that tutorial is trying to get at, but the gist of it is, each instruction pattern defined in TableGen matches a "fragment" of the DAG. LLVM will try bigger, more complex patterns first (as this corresponds to the case where a single instruction does a lot of things at once). This is done repeatedly until either the entire DAG contains only machine instructions, or a "selection failure" happens (i.e. there are no patterns that can match the current DAG node).

Comment: For some more detail into the topic, check out Eli Bendersky's blog post: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/02/25/a-deeper-look-into-the-llvm-code-generator-part-1